# iOS Swift : How to create textfield with image

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

New to iOS.Learning iOS swift by blogs and online materials. I want to create login form which looks like below. Importantly icon before textfield. How can I achieve that ? Please suggest

And how can i add logo on whitespace top? do i need to add bar item and add picture/logo?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve in `swift` like below :

```
let leftImageView = UIImageView()
leftImageView.image = leftImage

let leftView = UIView()
leftView.addSubview(leftImageView)

leftView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20)
leftImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 20)

textField.leftView = leftView
```

For `Objective C` try something like this

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 26, 26)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];

UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
[paddingView addSubview:imgView];
[txtField setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[txtField setLeftView:paddingView];
```

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding of your question, What i would suggest is the icon images you want to have on your interface. Open up the folder that has the xcode project in it. Click the top folder the one above the xcode project click assets. You know you are in the right folder when you get to the folder that has appicon folder in it. Put the images there. Then pull up your project next to the folder and dragg the items into your xcode project under the tab that says main storyboard then click the blue button in the bottom righthand corner now search your object library for image view drag that onto your interface then click the attributes inspector then about the top drop down add the image that you added before. Hope this helps.

Comment: please check other comment

Comment: Thanks buddy. I have my assets ready. But what im looking exactly is the lock symbol icon before textbox with placeholder "Password"..Do i need to add image view on left of textbox to display (lock/user) icon ??

Comment: I couldnt tell you off the top of my head (im not at my computer right now) i would suggest under the attributes inspector.... now going out on a limb here... you could try copy pasting the charecters from the emoji keyboard into the placeholder field ..... it may not be the best way or the right way of doing it.... but theres a chance it could work.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a nib with your image.

for example

```
let customNavBarView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SomeXibView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! UIView

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.inputView = customNavBarView
```

so far I've done this with mine and it works